# How to deserialize unzoned datetime to zoned using Jackson

Tags: java, datetime, kotlin, jackson

I'm looking for the simplest way of deserializing unzoned datetimes, such as `2021-03-31 00:00:00` into an `OffsetDateTime` with a statically-defined timezone. These are API responses from a third-party, they don't include timezones but their docs state that all timestamps are in a specific zone.

I thought that `ObjectMapper.setTimeZone()` would work, but I'm not having any luck with that. Kotlin example to illustrate:

```
data class Bar(
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    val timestamp: OffsetDateTime
)

@Test
fun `foo`() {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        .configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, true)
        .registerModule(KotlinModule())
        .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Phoenix"))

    val serialized = "{\"timestamp\":\"2019-01-01 00:00:00\"}"

    val deserialized: Bar = mapper.readValue(serialized)
}
```

That throws an exception `Unable to obtain ZoneOffset from TemporalAccessor`. Changing the field type to `LocalDateTime` works. Shouldn't Jackson contextually deserialize using the supplied timezone?

I know I can write a custom deserializer, but was hoping to get this simpler approach working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the hood Jackson does similar to the following:

```
val parsed: TemporalAccessor = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2019-01-01 00:00:00")
val result = OffsetDateTime.from(parsed) //Fails, but LocalDateTime.from(parsed) would have succeeded

//Time zone adjusting happens after that
```

So, I believe, you have to write your custom deserializer for this:

```kotlin
data class Bar(
    @JsonDeserialize(using = OffsetDateTimeDeserializer::class)
    val timestamp: OffsetDateTime
)

class OffsetDateTimeDeserializer(vc: Class<*>? = null) : StdDeserializer<OffsetDateTime>(vc) {
    companion object {
        private val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .parseDefaulting(
                ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS,
                //God bless Phoenix for not using DST
                TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Phoenix").rawOffset.toLong() / 1000 //Convert from milliseconds to seconds
            )
            .toFormatter()
    }

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): OffsetDateTime =
        OffsetDateTime.parse(p.valueAsString, formatter)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom deserializer or changing to the `LocaleDateTime` are the only options in my opinion...

From the implementation of `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDesirializer` we can see, that the time zone of the mapper does not enter parsing logic of `java.time` types.

```
try {
    TemporalAccessor acc = _formatter.parse(string);
    value = parsedToValue.apply(acc); // creation of OffsetDateTime from the TemporarAccessor is done here
    if (shouldAdjustToContextTimezone(context)) {
        return adjust.apply(value, this.getZone(context));
    }
} catch (DateTimeException e) {
    value = _handleDateTimeException(context, e, string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the other answers that you need to build a custom deserializer. Here’s how I would do the parsing in Java. Then I trust you to wrap in a deseializer and translate to Kotlin.

I first declare:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
private static final ZoneId thirdPartyZone = ZoneId.of("Brazil/Acre");
```

Fill in the known specific time zone. Then the conversion is:

```
    String valueAsString = "2021-03-31 00:00:00";

    OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse(valueAsString, formatter)
            .atZone(thirdPartyZone)
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    
    System.out.println(odt);
```

Output:

> 2021-03-31T00:00-05:00

This code also works with time zones that have summer time (DST) and other time anomalies.

Don’t use `TemporalAccessor`. Its documentation says:

> This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be
> widely used in application code. Instead, applications should create
> and pass around instances of concrete types, such as `LocalDate`.
> There are many reasons for this, part of which is that implementations
> of this interface may be in calendar systems other than ISO. …

Link: [`TemporalAccessor` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html).